# How do I add diagonal blocks to a responsive design?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add something very similar to this design on a site I'm working on:

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/54794.html

Notice how the mediumturquoise blocks in the bg of the site are diagonal but remain responsive while also having elements in front of them?

How would one go about accomplishing something like this? Is it an image set to full width in css? If so, how do I add content in front of the element?

Here's a screenshot just in case the link expires or I'm not being clear as to what element I'm talking about:

http://screencast.com/t/yYwOuHidK

Comment: If you inspect that page's styles you'll notice that class: `.cherry-box.style_1:after` that uses this background image: http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_54794/wp-content/themes/theme54794/images/box_bottom.png . So next time use your developer tool and eventually use Goog for similar approaches!

Answer (score 0):

*Use a background image!*

```css
.bg-image {
    position: relative;
}
.bg-image img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px; /* corresponds to max height of 450px */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.bg-image h1 {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
}
.nav, .main {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="nav">nav area</div>
            <div class="bg-image">
                <img src="http://unplugged.ee/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/frank2.jpg">
                 <h1>This is centered text.</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="main">main area</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**See it in a new window (change browser size)**](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/EGgaN/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the CSS transform property like this:

```
<html>
   <div class="rotate-wrapper">
    <div class="my-rotated-div">
          <div class="rotated-div-content">
          My Content
          </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
my-rotated-div {
     -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     transform: rotate(45deg);
}
rotated-div-content {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Then you just apply the bootstrap styles to `rotate-wrapper` and you should be good to go.

If you just want the look of a rotated block you could just use a background image but then you have to micro manage the background-position to match up with what you want.